# How do I get a particular log rotated at a custom time on a debian system?

Tags: logrotate

On my debian system, I have many logs which are rotated daily through their config files located in the `/etc/logrotated.d/` directory.

I need to change the rotation time of a particular log, say `backup.log`; the rotation config is located in `/etc/logrotated.d/backup.conf`. I want to get `backup.log` rotated at 1:00 am, whithout changing the global rotation time.

How can I do  it?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

1. move `/etc/logrotated.d/backup.conf` to `/etc/logrotate_backup.conf`
2. add the following line to `/etc/crontab`

   ```
   0 1 * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate_backup.conf
   ```

   The rotation of `backup.log` will be activated at 1:00 am.

   Alternatively, you can put that line in a custom file in `/etc/cron.d/`. e.g `/etc/cron.d/logrotate_backup`.